# When do you progress to the next stage in the Lord of the Ring LCG?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

After you finish a stage in the Lord of the Ring LCG–whether it be by successfully questing or by a card effect–do you finish the current round before progressing to the next stage, or do you immediately travel to the next stage of the quest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reveal the next stage of the quest as soon as you complete the previous one.  Depending on the quest, there can be advantages (or disadvantages) to doing this at a non-standard time, such as through Legolas's ability to add progress during combat, but this is intended.